# Mark answers off-topic for the "accept ratio" value

Tags: discussion, accept-rate

When somebody answers to my question, but the answer is clearly not working, and there is no other answer, then I cannot accept an answer to my question. But since technically there is already an answer to my question, it counts to the "accept ratio" which will decrease because of this. After all, the computer can't decide whether this is a helpful answer and just calculates a ratio of two numbers.

What is the suggested way to handle this? Accept the answer although it's not working? Downvote the answer (which will hurt the poster, even if he wasn't initially aware of the situation)?

Comment: Acceptance ratio has been gone since last year

Comment: Accept rate [is not longer displayed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951/167443).

Comment: If the answer isn't working (i.e. it's wrong), why not downvote it? And why would you even consider accepting a wrong answer, even if accept rate was displayed. Have people pestered you about your accept rate in the past? If so, that's exactly why it was removed and you should forget all about it.

Answer (score 16):

If it doesn't work, downvote and comment. That's what downvotes are for.

Don't worry if you don't have 100% accept rate. You don't **have** to accept something if it didn't help.

Anyway, accept rate isn't even visible anymore, so people won't see it.